# generating dates and times for three months with lubridate

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I am looking to generate a 3 months date and time column with lubridate.

I have followed the suggestions already in stack overflow but mostly these are for dates only. Yet I want to generate a sequence for 3 months with time, alongside with 24hr.

A sample of the type of columns I want is here but this is only for a month yet I need it for 3 months:

```
> dput(interv)
  structure(c(1326585600, 1326589200, 1326592800, 1326596400, 1326600000, 
              1326603600, 1326607200, 1326610800, 1326614400, 1326618000, 
              1326621600, 1326625200, 1326628800, 1326632400, 1326636000, 
              1326639600, 1326643200, 1326646800, 1326650400, 1326654000, 
              1326657600, 1326661200, 1326664800, 1326668400, 1326672000), 
              class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

Comment: what is your desired outcome? Add it to your question.

Comment: @AndreElrico I have re-edited yet it was clear what I have wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sequence of POSIXt classes:

```
seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2012-01-15 01:00:00 CET"), 
           to = as.POSIXct("2012-03-16 01:00:00 CET"), 
           by = "hour")
```

Comment: Thank you, quick and elegant.

Comment: I have done it and apparently it generates a column until 23:00 and not day from 1st of Jan to 31st of Jan with all hours during the day. You know what I mean?

Comment: @GaB no i do not know what u mean, the context is undefined, pls open a new question on SO

Comment: sorry, I got it. I double checked your outcome and indeed it is a good one. Just being a bit confused with my task that I extrapolated to your answer which is good. Apologies. And again, thank you, you are very quick to help.